# Terminal: text coloring works, but not blinking

Tags: bash

I have raspberry PI connected to a monitor. I do not login into raspberry, it simple boots up and stays on the login screen. After the raspberry boots up, rc.local executes my shell script, which echos all the output from remote server's tail command to my monitor connected to raspberry:

```
/usr/bin/ssh somehost.com "tail -n 50 -f /log/global.log" > /dev/tty0
```

The log uses text coloring like this:

```
\033[38;5;235m Gray Text \033[0m
```

So far so good, but when I'm trying to get the text to blink like this:

```
\033[5;32;40mBlink Text\033[0m
```

The colors are set correctly on the monitor output, but the text doesn't actually blink. When I do:

```
echo -e "\033[5;32;40mBlink Text\033[0m"
```

On my ubuntu machine, it's blinking fine, but not through the raspberry on my monitor, even though all the color codes work. Any suggestions how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a plain console, or a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#X_Window_terminals) running on the GUI desktop?

Comment: @goldilocks I mean plain console. The one which comes up when raspberry boots up. I do not actually login into raspberry with keyboard. After 10 seconds it has booted up, my script simply starts to 'echo' the output to /dev/tty0, which results in output being printed in the original console (the same one that's on when booting up), thanks